# Equivalent Matlab/Python GridData Function in C#

Tags: c#, charts, oxyplot

Both Matlab and python have a griddata function which interpolates XYZ points to fit given data point coordinates. Is there a C# equivalent of this?

If not is there a good reference for creating my own function?

link to scipy example:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

I want to take arbitrary X,Y,Z triplets and plot them using Oxyplot's contour or heatmap capabilities, but am having trouble getting the data in the correct format.

Comment: Nothing built in, you would need a library and asking for library suggestions is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a work around and called a python script that uses Scipy's Griddata function from my code:

```
String command = "GridDataFunct.py "+ CurrPath + "\\temp.xyz";
ProcessStartInfo cmdMe = new ProcessStartInfo(PythonExePath);
cmdMe.Arguments = command;
Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdMe);
cmd.WaitForExit();
```